# Using local-variables in other methods?

Tags: java, variables, random, methods

I was trying to make a program that searches for a random number, but i had problems importing the "a" variable in the other method. I would be happy if i could get some explanation. I have already tried to make the variable static, but that doesn't work

```
import java.util.Random;

public class verschlüsselung {

    private static void nummber(int a) {
        Random r = new Random();
        a = r.nextInt(999);
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    private static void search(int b) {
        b = 0;
        if(b =! a) {
            for(b = 1; b =! a ; b++) {
                if(b == a) {
                    System.out.println("found the number " + b);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        nummber(0);
        search(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: `b =! a` alright but when b==a it will not execute the logic of the loop Moreover make number return type int return the random number generated and pass it to search

Comment: How does search(int b) know about a?

Comment: First of all, why do you send parameters into the methods when the first thing you do is change the value without using the one you gave them? Secondly, if you want a variable to be access by multiple methods, declare it outside of the methods as a class variable. Another option is to make your methods return a variable of the type you want.

Comment: Local variables are precisely that.  `a` doesn't exist in your `search` method.  You must use some sort of more global variable if you want to share values between the two methods.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as using local variables in other methods.
You can return the variable from one method. Than call this method from other and get there the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable 'a'  to be static and remove the parameter 'a' passed in the nummber()
function. This function does not need any input as it assigns the value of a random number to the global static variable 'a' which is accessed in the method search().

your declaration and method signature should read :

private static int a;
private static void nummber(){....}

Answer (score -1):

May this help you:

```
private static int nummber( int a){

    Random r = new Random();

    a =r.nextInt(999);

    System.out.println(a);

    return a;
}



private static void search(int b, int a){

    b = 0;

    if(b =! a){

        for(b =1; b =! a ; b++){

            if(b == a){

                System.out.println("found the number " + b);

            }

        }

    }

}


public static void main(String args[]){

    int a = nummber(0);
    search(0, a);


}
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what you did and why it works to solve the OP's problem.

Comment: this will search for an other "a"